# PHP date - Null returns December 1969

Tags: php, date, strtotime

My function grabs the date successfully, but when it is NULL it returns a date of December 1969. I get this is the unix epoch, but how would I get it to output a blank value instead?

Here is the line of code as it stands now:

```
            $project_date = date("F Y", strtotime($g["project_date"]));
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Test if it's `null` *before* you create the Date object.

```
$project_date = is_null($g["project_date"]) ? "" : date("F Y", strtotime($g["project_date"]));
```

http://www.php.net/is_null